# Mantener sesion iniciada entre vistas y luego Cerrar Sesion

Tags: nodejs, express, express-session, middleware

buenos dias. Estoy desarrollando una web con dos amgios de un e-commerce. Tenemos duda en como mantener la sesion iniciada cuando cambiamos de vistas y por ultimo como realizar el Logout para cerrar la sesion (este lo realizamos, pero al cerrar sesion nos redirecciona a: "/" que seria la home y nos tira  y no podemos comprobar si se cerro la sesion del usuario)
El formulario de Login ya esta realizado y funciona.

```
**Desde Routes**:

router.get("/logout", /*userMiddleware*/ authController.logout);
module.exports = router;

**Desde Controllers**:

logout: (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.id) {
      req.session.destroy();
    }
    res.render('index');
  }
};

module.exports = controller;

**Desde Views**:

<a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Cerrar Sesion</a>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Deberias de hacer href="/logout" porque sino te redirecciona a la home con href="/"

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Al colocar href="/logout" me redirecciona a esa views y me arroja el error "not found", lo cual supongo que es, por que no la tengo creada. 
Intente enviar un msj desde el Controllers, res.send "se ha cerrado la session" tampoco me lo toma

Comment: Mantener iniciada la sesión al cambiar páginas? Que tipo de autenticación estás usando? Te lo pregunto porque no debería cerrarse una sesión cuando cambias de secciones en un website; podrías manejar todo eso con tokens por ejemplo y dar caducidad pasado un tiempo.